# Soft 404 error in Google Search Console for a new PHP based website using AWS CloudFront

Tags: google-search-console, soft-404, amazon-cloudfront

I created a new PHP based website. I enabled AWS CloudFront on top of it.

When I am doing a URL Inspection on it using Google Console, I am getting a soft `404` error. It's reporting:

> URL is not available to Google

The default page is `index.php` and it works perfectly fine.

Is there an AWS CloudFront setting that I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!